# ¿Cómo eliminar el fondo blanco de una imagen insertada con fabric.js en un lienzo?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

equipo Necesito un gran favor de usted, tengo el siguiente problema: necesito eliminar el fondo blanco de una imagen insertada en un lienzo pero con la biblioteca fabricJs ya que el usuario puede cambiar el tamaño de la imagen, pero la necesito gratis de fondo, cualquier ayuda sería apreciada, este es mi código de inserción de imagen:

Codigo html:

```
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
```

Codigo javascript:

```
var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('canvas', {
    width: 500,
    height: 500
});

fabric.Image.fromURL(urlImg, function (img) {
  img.width = 100;
  img.height = 100;
  img.top = 50;
  img.left = 50;
  img.scaleX = 0.2;
  img.scaleY = 0.2;
  img.angle = 0;

  canvas.add(img).setActiveObject(img);

});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hay un filtro para eso en la documentacion de Fabric.JS.
http://fabricjs.com/docs/fabric.Image.filters.RemoveColor.html

```
var filter = new fabric.Image.filters.RemoveColor({
  threshold: 0.2,
  color: //Color a remover
});
object.filters.push(filter);
object.applyFilters();
canvas.renderAll();
```